# Difficulty with PHP function that displays a post's format in WordPress

Tags: functions, post-formats, sticky-post

I am working on a WordPress theme using [Bones](http://themble.com/bones/). I would like to be able to show some text just above the title of each post if the post is either featured, password protected or private.

So far I came up with the following - this is directly inserted into `index.php`, `single.php`, `archive.php` and `search.php` (not in a function in `functions.php`)

```
<?php if(is_sticky()): ?>
  <h6 class="post-format"><?php _e('Featured', 'bonestheme'); ?></h6>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($post->post_password): ?>
  <h6 class="post-format"><i class="icon-lock"></i> <?php _e('Protected', 'bonestheme'); ?></h6>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($post->post_status == 'private'): ?>
  <h6 class="post-format"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> <?php _e('Private', 'bonestheme'); ?></h6>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The code above works fine, however, I would like to improve it and put it a function in `functions.php`. So far I have come up wit the following.

```
function print_post_format(){

if(is_sticky()):
  printf( __( '<h6 class="post-format">%s</h6>', 'bonestheme' ), 'Featured' );

else($post->post_password):
  printf( __( '<h6 class="post-format"><i class="icon-lock"></i>%s</h6>', 'bonestheme' ), 'Protected' );

else($post->post_status == 'private'):
  printf( __( '<h6 class="post-format"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i>%s</h6>', 'bonestheme' ), 'Private' );

endif;
}
```

When calling this function, 'Featured' shows up, however, 'Protected' and 'Private' do not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Ian

Comment: Does it work if you add `global $post;` above your first if-statement? Just below your `function print_post_format(){`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, that solves most of the problem - However, I think I have an issue in my 'if'/'else' statement - If I let the whole chunk of code run, I get the following error 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ':' in C:\...\functions.php on line 340' - line 340 being the  first 'else' statement.

Comment: Ah yes, you should use `elseif()` instead of `else` since you are checking conditions.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out - I was just about to post my findings - many thanks!